# Marklogic Template Driven Extraction: How to define nullable in Javascript template?

Tags: javascript, marklogic

How to specify that a column in the schema should be nullable?

I tried adding a nullable attribute:

```
var myFirstTDE = xdmp.toJSON(
  {
    "template": {
      "context": "/match",
      "collections": ["source1"],
      "rows": [
        {
          "schemaName": "soccer",
          "viewName": "matches",
          "columns": [
            {
              "name": "id",
              "scalarType": "long",
              "val": "id",
              "nullable": 0
            },
            {
              "name": "document",
              "scalarType": "string",
              "val": "docUri"
            },
            {
              "name": "date",
              "scalarType": "date",
              "val": "match-date"
            },
            {
              "name": "league",
              "scalarType": "string",
              "val": "league"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  }
);

tde.validate( 
  [myFirstTDE]
);
```

But this gave me a template error:

```
"message": "TDE-INVALIDTEMPLATENODE: Invalid extraction template node: fn:doc('')/template/array-node('rows')/object-node()/array-node('columns')/object-node()[1]/number-node('nullable')"
```

For a template defined using XQuery, adding nullable to the column works:

```
<column>
  <name>ISSN</name>
  <scalar-type>string</scalar-type>
  <val>Journal/ISSN</val>
  <nullable>true</nullable>
</column>
```

How to do the same thing using JS/Json?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `"nullable": true` instead of zero..

HTH!

Comment: Argh, sorry for the stupid question. I had actually tried it before as "nullable": "true" and didn't think to use a native boolean instead